# How do you organize Excel VBA code within a multipage userform?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Other than creating comment blocks, are there any other ways of organizing your Excel VBA code within a userform? I have multiple pages in the userform with each page containing its own controls (listboxes, textboxes, buttons, etc.). It would be neat if there was a way to group my controls on the basis on which page they belong too almost in an object-oriented manner. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you ever heard of [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com/)?

Comment: No I have not actually. But it is something that I could look into! Thanks!